# Как забрать значение из INPUT'а

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии строку текста

```
<div id="s"><p>Text</p></div>
```

на ее месте появлялся `INPUT`. Причем по умолчанию текст внутри него ставал как та строка. А при уводе мышки с `INPUT`'а введенный текст заносился в переменную, а сам `INPUT`, пропадая оставлял на своем месте текст.

Если делать

```
$("div#s").html('<input type="text" />');
```

,то текст ввести не получается. Подскажите что делать в этой ситуации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой способ, на мой взгляд, сделать div. В него положить два элемента, ваш div и скрытый input. Подписывайтесь на событие `onclick` для div'а и на события `onmouseout` у input'а. По событию для div'а назначаете ему `display:none;`, а input'у  `display:block;`. Аналогично для input'а.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="s"><p>Text</p></div>
    <input id="input_id" style="display:none;" value="">
</div>

$("#s").click(function(event){
    $("#s").css("display", "none");
    $("#input_id").css("display", "block");    
});

$("#input_id").mouseout(function(event){
    $("#input_id").css("display", "none");    
    $("#s").text($("#input_id").val());    
    $("#s").css("display", "block");
});
```

Comment: @Expert, вы можете показать свою реализацию? Только чтоб при `onmouseout` INPUT пропадал и на своем месте оставлял введенный текст.

Comment: @Expert, у меня получилось как вы сказали. Только я так понял это #s в первом случае. И не .text(), а val().

Comment: Хм а не `$("#container").mouseout`? По идее после клика #s уже невидим и mouseout для него сработать не может.

Comment: @Sh4dow, я думаю `input_id`, но можно и `container`. Опячатка.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#s').click(function(){
    if(!this.getElementsByTagName('input').length){
        $(this).append('<input type="text" value="'+this.innerHTML+'" />').find('input')[0].focus();
    }
});
$('#s input').live('focusout', function(){
    $(this).parent.html(this.value);
});
```

Comment: //this.getElementsByTagName('input').length
    $(this).find('input').length

Comment: Тоже можно. Это относится к личным заморочкам, просто я стараюсь не вызывать лишний раз $() для тривиальных действий. =)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div#s").click(function(){
    var text = $(this).text(); //если надо текст без тега "p", то заменить на $("p",this).text()
    $(this).html('<input type="text" value="'+text+'" onmouseout="set_field($(this))" />');
    $("div#s input").focus();
})

function set_field(e){
    // в переменно "e" у вас попадает текст из инпута, делайте с ним что нужно
}
```

Comment: @DemoS, у меня не получается ввести текст в INPUT. В коде нет ошибки?

Comment: Поправил. Добавил `$("div#s input").focus();`

Comment: @DemoS, теперь текст вводится, но функция `set_field(e)` не вызывается.